# Box not moving in animated box tutorial

Tags: gazebo-tutorial

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

I'm trying to follow the animated box tutorial. When I run gazebo with animated_box.world, I see the box in the middle of the world but it does not move. Then when I try using the gz topic interface to view the pose, it comes up but doesn't have any pose information.

I'm using gazebo 5.1

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12457/box-not-moving-in-animated-box-tutorial/) by [sm02](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2425/sm02/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-01-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-01-28**:
Can you run gazebo in verbose mode and see if you're getting any errors? `gazebo --verbose`

**Comment by [sm02](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2425/sm02/) on 2016-01-28**:
I just tried 'gazebo --verbose animated_box.world' and I received the following warnings and errors:

[Wrn] [gazebo.cc:186] Waited 1seconds for namespaces.
[Err] [Plugin.hh:153] Failed to load plugin libanimated_box.so: libanimated_box.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems that the plugin was not added to `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`, so Gazebo can't find it.

Be sure to move into your build folder and add it to the path like this:

```
 export GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH=`pwd`:$GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH
```

As explained in the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=animated_box&cat=build_robot#Animateboxcode).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sm02](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2425/sm02/) on 2016-01-28**:
I had done that, but I just realized that I used ' instead of `
It works now, thank you!

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2016-02-23**:
What is the default value of $GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH, i guess I changed mine by mistake?

**Comment by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) on 2016-02-23**:
I believe it is empty by default.

**Comment by [meha](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2288/meha/) on 2016-02-23**:
Yep, Thanks !!